# when i search my database instead of getting results i get error 500

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a website that is supposed to search the database for a specific id, but i get an error 500 when the submit button is clicked

i am running php7 and the latest mysql, ive tried removing un-needed code, ive tried changing the method i use to get information from the database, no luck

"dbh.inc.php"

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "chromebook";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

---

"search.inc.php(destination page, shows results)"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "dbh.inc.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Searching For Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];

if ($search == "") {
echo "<p>You Didn't Submit Data! Try Again!</p><a 
href="myurlusuallyisherebutitsforaimportantthingandidontwantusersgoingtoit"</a>";
exit;
}

$search = strtoupper($search);
$search = strip_tags($search);
$search = trim($search);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM chrome WHERE Teacher LIKE '%search%'");

echo "<table class="table" border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Room Number</th>
<th>Teacher</th>
<th>Front Barcode</th>
<th>Back Barcode</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['RoomNum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Teacher'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FrontId'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Barcode'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

i expect the page to load with the results asked from the database, instead i get an "http error 500" message from my browser

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Missing string termination on the first error. It you look at the webserser error log it would tell you the line in error.

Answer (score 1):

First parameter of the `mysqli_query` should be `$conn`

search.inc.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "dbh.inc.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Searching For Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>";
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];

if ($search == "") {
echo "<p>You Didn't Submit Data! Try Again!</p><a 
href="myurlusuallyisherebutitsforaimportantthingandidontwantusersgoingtoit"</a>";
exit;
}

$search = strtoupper($search);
$search = strip_tags($search);
$search = trim($search);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chrome WHERE Teacher LIKE '%search%'");

echo "<table class='table' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Room Number</th>
<th>Teacher</th>
<th>Front Barcode</th>
<th>Back Barcode</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['RoomNum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Teacher'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FrontId'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Barcode'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>` is incomplete; add the closing `";`

Unclosed `if` statement at `if(isset($_POST['search'])) {`

Unescaped double quotes on `echo "<p>You Didn't Submit Data! Try Again!</p><a 
href="myurlusuallyisherebutitsforaimportantthingandidontwantusersgoingtoit"</a>";` and `echo "<table class="table" border='1'>`

Also, I would highly recommend adding some error checking to your code so these 500 errors aren't a total mystery.

This works great for on page error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

So in total, replace your existing code with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Searching For Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// added error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>"; //fixed
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    if ($search == "") {
        echo "<p>You Didn't Submit Data! Try Again!</p><a href=\"myurlusuallyisherebutitsforaimportantthingandidontwantusersgoingtoit\"</a>"; // escape quotes
        exit;
    }

    $search = strtoupper($search);
    $search = strip_tags($search);
    $search = trim($search);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chrome WHERE Teacher LIKE '%search%'"); // connection param added

    echo "<table class=\"table\" border='1'>  // escape quotes
    <tr>
    <th>Room Number</th>
    <th>Teacher</th>
    <th>Front Barcode</th>
    <th>Back Barcode</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['RoomNum'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Teacher'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['FrontId'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Barcode'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($conn);
} // closing bracket from main 'if' statement
?>
```

Comment: usually i do, but i couldnt think of any on the spot, thanks!

Comment: add the error reporting and you should find the rest